# Why user name is undefined ? If I change Id="name"("nam" with "name')?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I create a simple messenger web app with node express socket.io.
but the result of user name is undefined.(if i change user id,then it will work,but why?)
**app.js**

```
const app = express();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("connected", socket.id);

  socket.on("chat", data => {
    console.log(data.name);

    io.sockets.emit("chat", data);
  });
});

http.listen("3000", () => {
  console.log("messenger is on!");
});
```

**index.html**

```
<body class="container">
    <div id="input">
        <input type="text" id="nam" placeholder="what is your name?" />         // user name
        <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="type your message..." />
        <button onclick="clicked()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="send">
            send
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="contener">
        <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();

        var nam = document.getElementById("nam");
        var message = document.getElementById("message");
        var send = document.getElementById("send");
        var output = document.getElementById("output");

        function clicked() {
            socket.emit("chat", {
                name: nam.value,
                message: message.value
            });
        }
        socket.on("chat", data => {
            output.innerHTML += `<p>${data.name} <br> ${data.message}</p>`;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

*If I change all **"nam"** with **"name"**,then It will not work! whyyy?*

I don't know what's wrong.
Give it a try,by replace all **nam** with **name**

Comment: Is there some other element that `name` is conflicting with? Would `input_name` or `in_name` be an acceptable alternative?

Comment: Note this has the potential for some pretty severe XSS issues, so you may want to lock that down before you go live.

Comment: There is no other external code.Only core code.no other element that ```name``` is conflicting with.

Answer (score 1):

[image: a busy cat]

just replace all **nam** with **name**

```
<body class="container">
    <div id="input">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="what is your name?" />
        <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="type your message..." />
        <button onclick="clicked()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="send">
            send
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="contener">
        <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();

        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var message = document.getElementById("message");
        var send = document.getElementById("send");
        var output = document.getElementById("output");

        function clicked() {
            socket.emit("chat", {
                name: name.value,
                message: message.value
            });
        }
        socket.on("chat", data => {
            output.innerHTML += `<p>${data.name} <br> ${data.message}</p>`;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```